# Built-in Actions not showing up

Tags: facebook, open-graph-beta

I know that there are some built-in objects (episode, article, tv show) and actions (watch, read , play , listen)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/builtin/

But I'm not being able to add them within my app.

The only objects (from open graph) that I can add, besides my custom objects under my app namespace, are:

```
website
book
profile
game
game achievement
```

Am I missing something here ?